# web.py rendering wrong page, path not correct

Tags: python, session, web.py

I'm working with web.py on a project with a user authentication component. This project has a `/demo` directory and a `/register` directory.

The problem is that for some reason, clicking the button meant to travel to the `/register` directory goes to `/demo` instead. Interestingly, if I type `/register` at the end of the URL, `/register` appears properly. The URL is different in this case, lacking the `?register=Register` part that comes from clicking the button.

The specific error that appears when I click on the register button is this:

`type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /demo
__template__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

The code that it points to as a problem area is this:

```
class demo:
   def GET(self):
      render = create_render(session.get('privilege', 0))
      return '%s' % render.demo() # Specifically this line generates the error.
```

I don't think there is any weird fall through, as in the code there are two classes implemented between the `register` class and the `demo` class. They're actually implemented in the order they're displayed in the `urls` list, with `reset` and `profile` in between the two.

I don't think there is anything wrong with my `urls` list:

```
urls = (
  '/', 'index',
  '/register', 'register',
  '/reset', 'reset',
  '/profile', 'profile',
  '/demo', 'demo',
  '/entropy', 'entropy',
)
```

Here also is the HTML code for the buttons:

```
<form action="demo" method="GET">
   <input type="submit" name="demo" value="Demo"/>
<form/>

<form action="register" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Other potentially relevant bits of code:

`register.GET()`:

```
class register:   
    def GET(self):
        reg_form = forms.registration_form()
        render = create_render(session.get('privilege'))
        return render.register()
```

`create_privilege(privilege)`: (Explained [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthpgsql), at #4)

```
def create_render(privilege):
    if logged():
        render = web.template.render('templates/logged', base='base')
    else:
        render = web.template.render('templates/', base="base")
    return render
```

So, I suppose, the final question is this: Why is the button rendering the wrong page? I can post more code if need be!

Thank you!

Comment: have you try `/` in `action="/demo"` and `action="/register"`  ?

Comment: Okay, so when I replace `action="/demo"` with `action="/"` it works fine and directs to the `/` directory. When I replace the other one with `action="/"` it _still_ attempts to go to the URL `/demo?register=Register` as opposed to `/register?register=Register

Comment: I don't mean `action="/"` but `action="/register"` - `register` with `/`. Now you have `action="register"` - `register` without `/`. The same with `action="/demo"` :)

Comment: Haha, I understand now. Unfortunately doing that doesn't change anything, but do you think we could be on to something from my misinterpreted attempt?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Somehow, for some reason, the ORDER of the buttons `demo` and `register` mattered, and swapping them let both pages redirect properly. Very strange.

Comment: it is strange - ORDER shouldn't has matter. Rather ORDER in `urls = (...)` can has matter because it can use first matching url instead of expected url.

Comment: I figured it out! There was an issue in my HTML tags, haha. Demo was not closed properly, ending in `<form/>` instead of `</form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! There was an issue in one of the HTML buttons, a `form` tag was not closed properly. What a silly error.